# WPF application: Tool tip not started all across all my application

Tags: wpf, material-design, tooltip

I have `WPF` application and I am using `materialDesign`.

This is my `app.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ToolTip.xaml"/>
               </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

My `style`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Silver"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"/>
        <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Bottom"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="10000"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.HorizontalOffset" Value="-20"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.Placement" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowsToolTipOnKeyboardFocus" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
                    <Border x:Name="Root" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource SettingsLeftMenueBackgroundColor}" Background="{DynamicResource ToolTipBackgroundColor}">
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsOpen" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Some `control`:

```
<Button Name="btnSettings"
        Padding="0"
        Cursor="Hand"
        Command="{Binding OpenSettingsFormCommand}">
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Content="Settings"
                 ToolTipService.Placement="Top"/>
    </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

And I cannot see this `ToolTip` at all.
I try to remove `MaterialDesignTheme.ToolTip.xaml` from my `app.xaml` or add key into my `ToolTip` style and using this `style` via key but this not helped at all.

My `ToolTip` missing across all my `application`.

Comment: The MaterialDesign resource dictionary does not seem to be the issue, as you do not use it in the style as far as I can see. It works just fine for me. Either the issue is not in the presented code or it might be related to an issue in .NET 6 if you use it: [#6220](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/6220) / [6283](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/6283).

Comment: Yes I am using .NET 6, any solution ?